# A formula to return the start date of the Fiscal Year in Excel

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I currently have two date values: 4/18/2023 and 4/18/2022.

I am looking for a formula to return the start date of the Fiscal Year (for us, it's July 1st).

So for example:

- If the date is 4/18/2023, I want it to return 7/1/2022.
- If the date is 4/18/2022, I want it to return 7/1/2021.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `=DATE(YEAR(A1)-1,7,1)` where A1 is the cell storing the date.

Comment: Thanks! How do I adjust it for when the date is July 1st?

Comment: Well, that's not what you have asked. Anyway, i'd say something like `=IF(A1=DATE(YEAR(A1),7,1),A1,DATE(YEAR(A1)-1,7,1))`.

Comment: Found another way! But thanks for your help. =IF(AND(MONTH(B7)=7,DAY(B7)=1),B7,DATE(YEAR(B7)-1,7,1))

Comment: Well, that's basically it. Still it's nice you didn't just waited for the answer. Well done.

Comment: What about `8/10/2023` with your formula above it would return `7/1/2022`

Comment: for that I would use: `=DATE(YEAR(B7)-(B7>=DATE(YEAR(B7),7,1)),7,1)`

Comment: oh sorry, my logic was backwards: `=DATE(YEAR(B7)-(B7<DATE(YEAR(B7),7,1)),7,1)`

Comment: this may be easier to read `=DATE(YEAR(A1)-IF(MONTH(A1)<7,1,0),7,1)`

Comment: I suggest:  `=DATE(YEAR(A1)-(MONTH(A1)<7),7,1)`

Answer (score 0):

If A2 is your actual date and B2 needs to be your fiscal date, then write this formula in cell B2:

```
=IF(DATE(YEAR(A2);7;1)>A2;DATE(YEAR(A2)-1;7;1);DATE(YEAR(A2);7;1))
```